# Repressing logging from another package

Tags: java, logging

My code requests a DB to see if an object is present and then sets a value. The problem is even if the object is present, my logs get flooded with their logging code. How can I suppress these logging statements?

Comment: What logging framework are they using? (If you don't know, sometimes it's possible to guess from the output so you could post some of that)

Comment: You can also guess by looking at the JARs that come with your ORM (or whatever it is you're using to access the DB).  Log4j?  commons-logging? if there's nothing then it's probably JDK logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! If you provide information about what logging system you use and other systematic information that could be helpful (like what db, where are the logs you want to suppress etc.) then someone will tell you how it can be done in your situation.